# How do you define a "one to many" doctrine association that allows the user to add a new "one"?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I'm trying to define my doctrine entities for use with Symfony2 and am am unclear how about to define an association. The below example is for customers compiling a wishlist of components they would like for a custom-made bicycle.

A `BikeEnquiry` object can:

- only ever take one frame
- by default takes two wheels (but could be zero or more)

However, regarding the accessories, I'm less sure about how these should be mapped.

The user should be able to select from a dropdown of accessories to see all the items we have in the database - however, they should also be able to manually enter a description of what they are looking for if it does not exist (such as a new product on the market). I would like this new accessory then be added to the Accessory database table - it would also be good to have it flagged up as an unvalidated item for my review.

Below is my attempt as defining the entities and annotation associations:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity **/
class BikeEnquiry 
{
    private $BikeEnquiryid;
    private $frameid;

   /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Wheel", mappedBy="wheelid")
    **/
    private $wheelid;

   /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Accessory")
    * @JoinTable(name="BikeEnquires_accessories",
    *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="BikeEnquiryid", referencedColumnName="BikeEnquiryid")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="accessoryid", referencedColumnName="accessoryid", unique=true)}
    *      )
    **/ 
    private $accessories;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->accessories = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity **/
class Frame
{
   /**
    * @OneToOne(targetEntity="BikeEnquiry")
    * @JoinColumn(name="BikeEnquiryid", referencedColumnName="BikeEnquiryid")
    **/
    private $frameid;
}

/** @Entity **/
class Wheel
{
   /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="BikeEnquiry")
    * @JoinColumn(name="BikeEnquiryid", referencedColumnName="BikeEnquiryid")
    **/
    private $wheelid;
}

/** @Entity **/
class Accessory
{
    private $accessoryid;
}
```

Comment: You should have a closer look at you ERD (Entity Relation Diagram).
But inside the BikeEnquiry Entity you should have a One-to-One relation with Frame, saying one BikeEnquiry must have one Frame.
And a One to Many relation with Wheel.(saying you can have one or more wheels)

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the code in my question as you pointed out

Comment: No do not use OneToOne. In that case only one BikeEnquiry could have one of the frames. The next BikeEnquiry could not take that frame anymore. ManyToOne is okay. I see that you use @ and not @ORM/ annotations while the last one is common in Symfony.

Comment: using different entities like frame, wheel, seat etc etc. versus using one "accessory" entity is a difficult decision although i think i should choose the last one.

Comment: Thanks - I'll change back to ManyToOne for bikeOrder-Frame then. I can't use one accessory entity as a 'capture all' as there are other fields for each entity in the database tables. For my accessory entity though is it possible to have the user entering new terms to the database table?